# Expression formation in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, expression

I have a delimited text later and I need to only display every tenth label from a series of field values using an expression.

What’s the easiest way to do this?

[image: output image with all labels]

Field values are a range of ascending numbers.

[image: image 2-output displayed on map]
[image: image-delimited text file, field value=station_va]

Comment: Sharing some example data would make it at least easier.

Answer (score 3):

In this very specific case of labeling using a continuous value (aka ID) you can use the following expression for a label:

`if("ID-column" % 10 = 0,"ID-column",'')`

Replace `"ID-column"` with the actual name of said column. This expression checks, if the modulo 10 of your ID is 0, and if, labels the feature with this ID. Otherwise the label is empty.

If your ID-column isn't an integer column, you will have to use `to_int`.

Comment: Excellent! Yes thank you